# How to trim string in command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a lot of shortcut urls in a directory.

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ReadItLaters>dir *.url /b
aaa.url
bbb.url
ccc.url

...

zzz.url
```

I want to pickup those url.
so I wrote command like this.

```
for %i in (*.url) do @type "%i" | find "URL="
```

that outputs like this.

```
URL=https://www.example.com/aaa.html
URL=https://www.example.com/bbb.html
URL=https://www.example.com/ccc.html

...

URL=https://www.example.com/zzz.html
```

It tastes nice. but I want to get url strings WITHOUT "URL=".

I wish to output like this.

```
https://www.example.com/aaa.html
https://www.example.com/bbb.html
https://www.example.com/ccc.html

...

https://www.example.com/zzz.html
```

How can I replace "URL=" to empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `for /f` loop to process the lines:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('type *.url 2^>nul^|find "URL="') do @echo %%a
```

or a bit saver (in case the URLs contain `=`)

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('type *.url 2^>nul^|findstr /b "URL="') do @echo %%b
```

See `for /?` for details.

(Note: this is batch file syntax. If you want to use it directly on the command line, replace each `%%` with a single `%`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use substring, skipping the first 4 characters in your string: **`%_url:~4%`**

**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**

```
for /f %%i in ('type *.url^|find "URL="')do set "_url=%%~i" && call echo/%_url:~4%
```

**[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**

```
for /f %i in ('type *.url^|find "URL="')do set "_url=%~i" && call echo/%_url:~4%
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Substring in Set command (Refer: `%_url:~4%`)](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

Comment: This command is easy for me to understand. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the information for multiple URL files, without the need to nest two `for` loops. You can take advantage of `FindStr`'s ability to search through multiple files directly.

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IR "^URL=http" "*.url" 2>NUL"')Do @Echo %%H
```

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```batch-file
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %G In ('""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IR "^URL=http" "*.url" 2>NUL"')Do @Echo %H
```